# Exports: How can a small amount of export make really high income

Tags: international-trade

I'm currently researching for a school project about Thailand.

I found the wonderful Observatory of Economic Complexity Website.

There are two visualizations I don't quite understand: 
https://atlas.media.mit.edu/en/visualize/tree_map/hs92/export/tha/all/show/2015/ 
https://atlas.media.mit.edu/en/visualize/stacked/hs92/export/tha/all/show/1995.2016/

How can it be that Animal products (light yellow) are only 1.3% of total exports but make the most money.

Maybe I didn't understand the Stacked Visualization right. So maybe that's my mistake.

EDIT: OK; I just found out that I misread the chart. I was a little bit confused obviously. These stacked line charts are completely unlogical to me

Comment: How much does this category of exports make?

Comment: @london 230 Billion USD (If I understood the visualizations right)

Comment: is this the sum of all animal products?

Answer (score 3):

What you're asking<sup>1</sup> stems from a more general question

> "How can such a small amount of some export $Q$ make the most money out of all the exports?"

To that the answer is to simply recall the standard formula for [Total Revenue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_revenue).

i.e.

$$TR=P \times Q$$

Even though the quantity of export $Q$ is small it could be that the price for $Q$ (be that for whatever reason) be the cause for why it makes more revenue relative to the countries other exports.

Hope this is helpful!

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> I could be wrong</sub>

Comment: Nothing you say in your answer is wrong, but this is not the issue with the OP's question. The OP had misread the value of animal product exports on the chart as per LimonadaPT's answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of Animal products, you can see in the chart that the corresponding yellow bar is quite small (1,3% of the visual space). It starts at 228B and finishes at 231B, thus ~3B is the amount of animal exports.

These stacked bars charts help to understand visually the contribution of each sector in the economy. Each line should be read as "How much is this sector adding to the GDP?" It helps to imagine that you would get all the money from the exports, wrap it in different colours and stack it up in a room - the end result would look like this chart.